# Get ID of submit button before validating with jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, jquery-validate

I've got a form that has a two different uses (create new post or update an existing post) that is displayed in a fancybox pop-over window.

I want to use two buttons for submitting the form; 'Save' and 'Save And Close'. The 'Save' button will simply submit the form and receive a 'success' message back from the server with a timestamp (so I can display a 'Last Saved' message).

The 'Save and Close' will get a success message back from the server and close the fancybox.

My trouble is, I can't figure out how to tell the submit handler which submit button was clicked so it knows whether to close the box on success or just display the timestamp...

I'm thinking if I can capture the ID of the submit button as it hits the validator that I can pass that to the success handler...

Here's my validator

```
$('#contact').validate({
    rules: {
        title: {
            required: true
        },
        comments: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 200
        }
    },
    messages: {
        comments: {
            maxlength: "Too much text. 200 chars. max."
        }
    }, 
    submitHandler: function() {
        $('#loading_contact').show();
        var formData = $("#contact").serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "admin.cfc?method=createPosting&returnformat=json",
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
            $('#formwrapper').empty();
            $('#formwrapper').html(data.message);
            }   
        });
    }
});
```

And my form...

```
<cfform name="contact" id="contact">
            <cfif arrayLen(errors)>
                <p>Please correct the following error(s):
                    <ul><cfloop index="e" array="#errors#">
                            <li>
                                <cfoutput>#e#</cfoutput>
                            </li>
                        </cfloop>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </cfif>
            <cfinput type="hidden" id="job_id" name="job_id">
            <p><label for="title" id="ltitle">Position Title</label></p>
            <cfinput style="color:black" type="text" id="title" class="oneliner required" name="title">
            <p><label for="comments" id="lcomments">Description</label></p>
            <cftextarea style="color:black;height:600px;" id="comments" name="comments" class="required"></cftextarea>
            <p style="padding:15px 0 0 0;"><cfinput style="background:none;border:none;text-decoration:underline;color:black;" type="submit" id="submit" value="Save" name="submit"><img id="loading_contact" src="../images/loading.gif" /> <cfinput style="background:none;border:none;text-decoration:underline;color:black;" type="submit" id="saveclose" value="Save and Close" name="saveclose"><img style="display:none;" id="save_close" src="../images/loading.gif" /></p>
        </cfform>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript's variables carry function scope so to pass the button that was pressed to your success handler, try the following:

```
 $(':button').click(function(){
       var type = $(this).attr('id');
       $('#contact').validate({  
          submitHandler: function() {
             $.ajax({success: function(data) {if(type===''){}} });
          };
       });
    });
```

I left out the code you already know - this is just your submithandler and successhandler for the validate and ajax methods with the passed variable

Comment: this was precisely the thing I was looking for. I don't know why it didn't seem obvious to me after looking at how simple the solution was. Thank you.

Comment: Interesting quirk on this method though... When the 'type' var is passed to the ajax success handler, it's not being refreshed. The first time the button is clicked (click 'Save' for example), it sets the var and does as expected, but if the page isn't refreshed and you click the other button 'Save and Close' the var inside the ajax success handler still thinks it is 'Save'. I've alerted the var upon submit and it's definitely changing the var there, but it's not getting passed along for some reason.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense,  'type' only exists for the duration of this function.  Once its done so is the variable. The next click should not only reassign the value of 'type' but the first variable shouldn't even be accessible.  Taking a shot in the dark without seeing your code, you probably have an "if-else" operation and if your using the triple = marks you need to make sure they match exactly.

Comment: lets see an html snippet to go along with this jquery

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to have both your buttons do a ajax post.  You can check if the form is valid first by going form.valid() see [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid).  The ajax post success call for the "close" option would also close the box.

Update:  You could also have the submit buttons set a field somewhere on the page and have your success handler read that field to determine if it should close the box or not.  Getting a little hacky, but it would work.

Answer (score 0):

i'm no sure how your sumbit handler is being called now, but removing that and using:

```
$('#submit').bind('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   submitHandler(false);
});
$('#saveclose').bind('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   submitHandler(true);
});
```

to sumbit the form should work. I mean you'll have a boolean passed in to the sumbitHandler that will be true if it needs to close.